# How to declare a scheduled event with delay informed dynamically on MassTransit?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

On Sample-ShoppingWeb's ShoppingCartStateMachine there is an configuration like this to schedule events:

```
 Schedule(() => CartExpired, x => x.ExpirationId, x =>
            {
                x.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                x.Received = e => e.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CartId);
            });
```

Note that "x.Delay" property, that is set on constructor, but on my case, i would like to inform that time delay dinamically.

```
When(ApproveOrder)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.EstimatedTime = context.Data.EstimatedTime;
                    context.Instance.Status = context.Data.Status;
                })
```

...and set an schedule event with "context.Data.EstimatedTime" Delay e.g.

There is a way to do that using "Schedule" declaration on state machine constructor class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Schedule` extension used within a state machine was enhanced to added support for dynamic delays. For example, you can do the following:

```
When(ApproveOrder)
    .Then(context => context.Instance.EstimatedTime = context.Data.EstimatedTime)
    .Schedule(CartExpired, context => context.Instance.EstimatedTime)
```

This will use the delay from the second argument instead of the one specified when the schedule was created.

Comment: I know this is old, but as i'm using the sample, i notice this doesn't seem to work. I haven't found any way to pass this delay dynamically

Comment: It's still in there if you're on any modern version of MassTransit. You can see a working example here: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AutomatonymousIntegration.Tests/ScheduleTimeout_Specs.cs#L254

Comment: ah, so that last parameter isn't to set the message expiration, it sets the delay! I'll give that a try

Comment: Update to the broken link in the comment above: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.Tests/ScheduleTimeout_Specs.cs